# Hoist two class variables out of OpenMP parallel loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm working on a parallel version of [`scrypt`](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) using OpenMP. The program is at the very end of the post.

The parallelizable part works fine (1) without OpenMP and (2) with OpenMP and the class variables `XY` and `V` in the loop:

```
// 2: for i = 0 to p - 1 do
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < parallel; ++i)
{
    SecByteBlock XY(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * 256U));
    SecByteBlock  V(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * cost * 128U));

    // 3: B_i <-- MF(B_i, N)
    const ptrdiff_t offset = static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(blockSize*i*128);
    Smix(B+offset, static_cast<size_t>(blockSize), cost, V, XY);
}
```

The `SecByteBlock` wraps `new` and `delete` and acts a lot like a `vector`. The problem is, `SecByteBlock` has a zeroizer. Every time the class is destructed all the memory is set to 0. Then, a new one is created for the thread at the top of the loop. It is inefficient.

I tried to hoist `XY` and `V` out of the loop so they would be destructed once. The attempts are shown below, but they all result in segmentation faults:

```
$ time OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./test.exe
Threads: 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

real    0m9.561s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m2.750s
```

How does one hoist a class variable out of the parallel for loop so it does not go through unwanted create/destruct cycles?

---

***Hoist out of loop***:

```
SecByteBlock XY(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * 256U));
SecByteBlock  V(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * cost * 128U));

// 2: for i = 0 to p - 1 do
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < parallel; ++i)
{
    // 3: B_i <-- MF(B_i, N)
    const ptrdiff_t offset = static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(blockSize*i*128);
    Smix(B+offset, static_cast<size_t>(blockSize), cost, V, XY);
}
```

***Thread private***:

```
SecByteBlock XY(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * 256U));
SecByteBlock  V(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * cost * 128U));

// 2: for i = 0 to p - 1 do
#pragma omp parallel for private(XY) private(V)
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < parallel; ++i)
{
    // 3: B_i <-- MF(B_i, N)
    const ptrdiff_t offset = static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(blockSize*i*128);
    Smix(B+offset, static_cast<size_t>(blockSize), cost, V, XY);
}
```

***Parallel section and thread private***:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    SecByteBlock XY(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * 256U));
    SecByteBlock  V(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * cost * 128U));

    // 2: for i = 0 to p - 1 do
    #pragma omp parallel for private(XY) private(V)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < parallel; ++i)
    {
        // 3: B_i <-- MF(B_i, N)
        const ptrdiff_t offset = static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(blockSize*i*128);
        Smix(B+offset, static_cast<size_t>(blockSize), cost, V, XY);
    }
}
```

---

Here is the test program. It is Valgrind, Coverity and Sanitizer clean with the class variables in the loop. The problems arise when hoisting them out of the loop.

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "secblock.h"
#include "scrypt.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>       

int main()
{
    int threads = 1;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    }
    std::cout << "Threads: " << threads << std::endl;

    using namespace CryptoPP;
    SecByteBlock derived(64);

    const byte pwd[] = "password";
    const byte salt[] = "NaCl";

    Scrypt scrypt;
    scrypt.DeriveKey(derived, derived.size(), pwd, 8, salt, 4, 1<<20, 8, 16);

    std::cout << "Derived: ";
    StringSource(derived, 16, true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
    std::cout << "..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is unclear whether the variables can be reused in several iterations without any kind of initialization. But let's assume this is the case.

then what if you declare the variable per thread, and then let OpenMP do the parallelization in the for loop

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Each OpenMP thread has its own variable
    SecByteBlock XY(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * 256U));
    SecByteBlock  V(static_cast<size_t>(blockSize * cost * 128U));

    // 2: for i = 0 to p - 1 do
    #pragma omp for
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < parallel; ++i)
    {
        // 3: B_i <-- MF(B_i, N)
        const ptrdiff_t offset = static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(blockSize*i*128);
        Smix(B+offset, static_cast<size_t>(blockSize), cost, V, XY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Giles. I'm not sure how I missed that combination during testing.